# How to return dynamic type depend on the parameter type in function

Tags: reactjs, function, typescript

My code look like this

```
const styles = ({palette, appStyle}: TTheme) => ({
  component: { backgroundColor: palette.primary},
  text: appStyle.text,

const withStyle = (customStyle) => 
  customStyle({
    palette: { primary: 'red'},
    appStyle: {text: {color: 'red'}},
  })
```

How can I define type of this function `const withStyle = (customStyle)`

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you asking what the type signature of `withStyle` is? Is `customStyle` of type `Style`?

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg both: withStyle and customStyle

I would like to apply this functions like this: 

withStyle(styles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a type parameter in the type signature of the function, something like this:

```
function withStyle<T extends TTheme, U>(styles: (T) => U) {
  ...
}
```

This means that the function `withStyle` takes a single argument that is itself a function that takes something of type `T`, which is a subclass of `TTheme` and returns something else of type `U`.

It's not really clear from your question what the type signatures are, but the key is that you need to use [generic type parameters](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

Comment: Thanks AndrewEisenberg. How can I write interface of that function?

Comment: Do you mean the type signature of the function? Why is this something that is necessary? Once you have a reference to the function, you can use it in a type signature with `typeof withStyle`. But this is only useful or interesting if you have multiple functions all of the same type.

Comment: I'm using HOC. That means I have to define again style in typescript.
For example I would like to create the interface like this:

interface ComponentPropsIn extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {} to help my component props contains styles props. So if you don't mind could you help me to create the interface called 'WithStyles'?

Comment: Related this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51373710/how-can-i-define-type-depend-on-function-parameter